# Cannot connect postgresql database through pgadmin 3

Tags: postgresql, odoo, pgadmin

I was trying to connect my database with my credentials through **pgadmin3** interface but it shows authentication error. But I can connect that same database and access everything through the terminal with the same credentials.

Is there anyone who got the same situation? How do I get rid of this issue ??
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What exactly is the error produced?

Comment: @ultrajohn This is the exact error message produced. An error has occurred:

10:30:43: Error: Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "odoo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution!

You have to change the `pb_hba.conf` file and change the lines

```
local all postgres peer 
local all all peer
```

to

```
local all postgres md5
local all all md5
```

Then restart postgres using `sudo service postgresql restart` command

Answer (score 1):

Is your database server localhost and you are using the command `#sudo -u odoo psql -h localhost`  to connect to it?

From the error message, it seems that the peer authentication is used for user `odoo` .
In this case, you don't have to set the password. (Password will not be used)

Do you want to keep using peer authentication or use password(md5) authentication?

In the former case, you should start pgadmin as `odoo` user and leave the `Host` field blank so that pgadmin connects using the local Unix socket rather than TCP.

In the latter case, you should change the `pb_hba.conf` like the following to let `odoo` user use the md5 authentication.

`local your-database odoo md5`